# How to make the table in latex?

Tags: tables

I already install all the packages but its still not working error given below
[image]Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'

```
     \begin{table}[htbp]
     \centering
     \caption{Add caption}
     \begin{tabular}{rcccccccccccc}
     \toprule
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Lat 34 Long 72}}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Jan}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Feb}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Mar}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Apr}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{May}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Jun}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Jul}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Aug}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Sep}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Oct}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Nov}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Dec}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \textbf{22-year Average} & 3.08  & 3.77  & 4.76  & 6.18  & 7.31  & 7.88  & 6.96  & 6.21  & 5.87  & 5.01  & 3.76  & 2.86 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the question? you seem to have latex code for the table ...

Comment: From given code is not possible reproduce this table. Please add used packages all from ``\documentclass{...} ...\begin{document} ... \end{document}``

Comment: @Zarko now check the error

Answer (score 3):

The error means you're not loading the `multirow` package, but you don't need it, for it's easier to specially treat one cell than all 13 in the header row; with `makecell` it's easy.

The only problem is to reduce the table so it fits; I used `\small` and 2.2pt as `\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}

\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{12}{c}@{}}
\toprule
\bfseries\makecell[l]{Lat 34\\ Long 72} &
  \textbf{Jan} & \textbf{Feb} & \textbf{Mar} & \textbf{Apr} &
  \textbf{May} & \textbf{Jun} & \textbf{Jul} & \textbf{Aug} &
  \textbf{Sep} & \textbf{Oct} & \textbf{Nov} & \textbf{Dec} \\
\midrule
\textbf{22-year Average} &
3.08  & 3.77  & 4.76  & 6.18  & 7.31  & 7.88 &
  6.96  & 6.21  & 5.87  & 5.01  & 3.76  & 2.86 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]